# Encapsulate async method in Func<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, grpc

First, i hope the title is okay.

I have a Grpc Client with the well known greeter service and try to encapsulate the SayHelloAsync call in a Func.
But the => operator is redlined because he can not convert the expression he say.
It works if i remove any async/await.
Its probably because SayHelloAsync returns AsyncUnaryCall(which have an awaiter) instead of Task but at the end its
not a Grpc issue i guess, its just my missunderstanding.

Here is my try:

```
static async Task Main()
{
   var client = CreateGreeterClient();
   await UnsafeTask<Service.HelloReply>(async ()  =>
   {
       var result = await client.SayHelloAsync(new Service.HelloRequest { Name = greeter.Name });
       return Task<Service.HelloReply>.FromResult(result);
   });
   Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task<T> UnsafeTask<T>(Func<AsyncUnaryCall<T>> method) where T:class
{
   try
   {
      return await method();
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
      return null;
   }           
}
```

Any tip would be greatful.

Comment: Why exactly are you using `return Task<Service.HelloReply>.FromResult(result);`? Surely that should be just `return result;`?

Comment: Are you wrapping the task one too many times? Try just `return result;`

Comment: Side note: if the `AsyncUnaryCall` etc machinery is unsightly to you, then you might find protobuf-net.Grpc interesting; it builds on the same gRPC APIs, but has a more idiomatic .NET API shape

Comment: Nice plug @MarcGravell :) I'm hoping to start using it soon when we start moving from JSON to gRPC in my company

Comment: that was my first try  
 `code`
var result = await...
return result;
 `code`
but no luck.

Comment: `Func<Task<T>> method`

Comment: @aepot you made my day ;) thank you!